# Why the Chromium seems to be working even though the test is finished?

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, robotframework, chromium, ram

I ran tests many times in headless mode using robot framework and selenium on my Ubuntu server. But even though the tests are over, my ram usage has increased a lot. I got suspicious and downloaded htop and looked. Are these resource usages normal? Or are they still running in the background? What should I do to get my ram usage back to normal? I have shared the image link below.
My guess-> robot framework gives report.html and log files. So as far as I understand, the robot ends, but the chromium continues.

[IMAGE LINK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHGLo.png)

Answer (score 2):

Did you put a `driver.quit()` in your code? If not, the driver stay alive. You need to kill the task manually, or write a bash file to do it. I wrote a batch file for **Windows**, to kill all `chrome.exe` and `chromedriver.exe` when I'm testing my bot, you might be able to do something similar in bash:

```
@echo off
TASKKILL -F -IM chrome.exe
TASKKILL -F -IM chromedriver.exe
echo "####################################"
echo "#    DRIVER KILLED SUCCESSFULLY    #"
echo "####################################"
```

In this case, `@echo off` disable the print of the commands in the console, and the echo are not necessary.

Comment: Actually, I use the close browser keyword after all the tests because I use robot framework. Doesn't this keyword close the browser and driver?

Comment: In selenium, `close()` don't close the driver, but only the browser window. If you want to terminate the driver aswell, you need to use `quit()`